# nginx simple regex location

Tags: nginx, regex, regular-expressions

I need to set a location param in nginx if the first 5 digits of the url are numbers.

```
site.com/12345/ or site.com/12345
```

But I can't for the life of me seem to get the correct regular expression.

None of these work.

```
location ^/([0-9]) { }
location ^/(\d\d\d\d\d) {}
location /(\d\d\d\d\d) {}
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
location ~ "^/[\d]{5}" {
    # ...
}
```

`~` means the a regex location

`^` means the beginning of the line

`[\d]` is shorthand for character class matching digits

`{5}` shows that the digits must be exactly five, no more, no less

and `()` parentheses are not necessary if you do not want then to use grouping, $1, for example

Double quotes because curley braces used in regex must be enclosed in double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684463/curly-braces-and-from-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules

Comment: Oh, those double quotes! The use of `{}` demands the regex to be inside `""`. Thank you!

Comment: Also no need to end the string with any `$` symbol either.

Answer (score 7):

Try this syntax (tested on my server) :

```
location ~ ^/([0-9]+) {
  #...
}
```